# Eun una base de datos SQL como hacer para que un campo de una tabla solo acepte determinados valores

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

tengo el siguiente problema quiero que el campo role solo acepte dos valores 'USER_ROLE' o 'ADMIN_ROLE' como podria hacerlo?, lo que intente sin éxito alguno:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
    role VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'USER_ROLE',
    CHECK (role='USER_ROLE' OR 'ADMIN_ROLE'),
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que la mejor implementación es que tu campo sea del tipo `ENUM(val1, val2, val3, ...)`

Por ejemplo, en una migración de Laravel, tendrías `$table->enum('role', ['user_role', 'admin_role']);`

O en una sentencia SQL: `role ENUM('user_role', 'admin_role)`

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que necesitas tener la comparación completa en ambos lados del `OR`, puesto que solo se comparan datos booleanos.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
    role VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'USER_ROLE',
    CHECK (role='USER_ROLE' OR role='ADMIN_ROLE')
);
```